# How to get all orders?

Tags: api, soap, wsdl, sapb1, sap-business-one-di-api

I am using SOAP UI to use the B1WS/WebReferences WSDL's and was wondering if there is a way to get all orders back from it. 
I am using SAP Business One and need to get all orders back as a request in that, I have found a method called `getBPlist()` that gets a list of all business partners, but I want one that I can use to get all orders. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you better use the recordset that contains the di-api, you can do the conversion as well.

```
SAPbobsCOM.Recordset rs = ((SAPbobsCOM.Company)oCompany.GetDICompany()).GetBusinessObject(BoObjectTypes.BoRecordset);
rs.DoQuery("SELECT DocEntry, DocNum, DocDate, TaxDate, CardCode, CardName, DocTotal FROM OPOR ORDER BY DocDate ASC");
while (!rs.EoF)
{
    int DocEntry = rs.Fields.Item("DocEntry").Value;
    //OR
    DocEntry = rs.Fields.Item(0).Value;

    rs.MoveNext();
}
```

Comment: And if related data is needed like line items, order quantities, prices etc, subsequent database queries need to be done? correct?